# Laravel 5.5 Crud with Ajax: On Add/Delete/Update no changes without refresh and redirection issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, crud, laravel-5.5

I'm using `ajax` for `Crud` operations in my `laravel` app.
But I'm facing two issues, I've tried many solutions from stack overflow but none of it work.

**Problems:**

**1.** On Add/Delete/Update Operation unable to see changes without
    refresh, I've to refresh the page to see changes. (No benefits of Ajax then)

**2.** On success data
        redirect Url is not working too.

**Routes:**

```
//franchisors crud controller
Route::prefix('admin/franchisors')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/', 'AdminCrudController@index');
    Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'create', 'AdminCrudController@create');
    Route::match(['get', 'put'], 'update/{id}', 'AdminCrudController@update');
    Route::delete('delete/{id}', 'AdminCrudController@destroy');
});
```

**Controllers:**

```
   public function create(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->isMethod('get'))
            return view('admin.add_franchisor');
        else {
//            $rules = [
//                'name' => 'required',
//                'email' => 'required|email',
//            ];
//            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
//            if ($validator->fails())
//                return response()->json([
//                    'fail' => true,
//                    'errors' => $validator->errors()
//                ]);
            $franchisor = new Franchisors();
            $franchisor->name = $request->name;
            $franchisor->email = $request->email;
            $franchisor->password = $request->password;
            $franchisor->cnic = $request->cnic;
            $franchisor->address = $request->address;
            $franchisor->mobile = $request->mobile;
            $franchisor->shop = $request->shop;
            $franchisor->dist= $request->dist;
            $franchisor->coins = $request->coins;
//            $amount = $request->coins;
            $franchisor->save();
            $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Franchisor was successful added!');

            $franchisorID = $franchisor->id;
            $id = CoinRate::latest()->first()->id;
            $rate = CoinRate::latest()->first()->rate;
            $coins = new Coin();
            $coins->coinrate_id = $id;
            $coins->amount = $request->coins;
            $coins->total = $request->coins * $rate;
            $coins->type = 2;
            $coins->franchisor_id = $franchisorID;
            $coins->save();
            return redirect('admin/coins');


//            return \response()->json([
//                'fail' => false,
//                'redirect_url' => url('admin/franchisors')
//            ]);
        }
    }

   public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
        if ($request->isMethod('get'))
            return view('admin.add_franchisor', ['franchisors' => Franchisors::find($id)]);
        else {
//            $rules = [
//                'name' => 'required',
//                'email' => 'required|email',
//            ];
//            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
//            if ($validator->fails())
//                return response()->json([
//                    'fail' => true,
//                    'errors' => $validator->errors()
//                ]);

            $Franchisor = Franchisors::find($id);
            $Franchisor->coins = $request->coins;
            $Franchisor->name = $request->name;
            $Franchisor->address = $request->address;
            $Franchisor->cnic = $request->cnic;
            $Franchisor->shop = $request->shop;
            $Franchisor->email = $request->email;
            $Franchisor->password = $request->password;
            $Franchisor->mobile = $request->mobile;
            $Franchisor->dist = $request->dist;
            $Franchisor->save();
            return response()->json([
                'fail' => false,
                'redirect_url' => url('/admin/franchisors')
            ]);
//            return redirect('');
//            return Redirect::to('admin');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id,Request $request)
    {
        Franchisors::destroy($id);
        $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'User was successful added!');
        return redirect('admin');
    }
```

**Views:**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">{{isset($franchisors)?'Edit':'New'}} Franchisor</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-group row required">
            @if(isset($franchisors))
            <form class="form-horizontal" id="frm" novalidate method="POST" action="{{ url('admin/franchisors/update/'.$franchisors->id) }}">
             @else
        <form class="form-horizontal" id="frm" novalidate method="POST" action="{{ url('admin/franchisors/create') }}">
            @endif
                {{ csrf_field() }}
            @if(isset($franchisors))
                {{ method_field('PUT') }}
            @endif

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{isset($franchisors)?$franchisors->name:''}}" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" value="{{isset($franchisors)?$franchisors->email:''}}" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cnic" class="col-sm-2 control-label">CNIC</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{isset($franchisors)?$franchisors->cnic:''}}" id="cnic" name="cnic" placeholder="CNIC">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" value="{{isset($franchisors)?$franchisors->password:''}}" name="password" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Address" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8">
                    <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" value="{{isset($franchisors)?$franchisors->address:''}}" id="address" placeholder="Address">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Mobile" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Mobile</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobile" value="{{isset($franchisors)?$franchisors->mobile:''}}" id="Mobile" placeholder="Mobile">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Shop" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Shop</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Shop" value="{{isset($franchisors)?$franchisors->shop:''}}" name="shop" placeholder="Shop">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="dist" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Dist.</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dist" value="{{isset($franchisors)?$franchisors->dist:''}}" id="dist" placeholder="District">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Coins" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Coins</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Coins" value="{{isset($franchisors)?$franchisors->coins:''}}" name="coins" placeholder="Coins">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"> Close</button>
    {{--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Save </button>--}}
    {{--{!! Form::submit("Save",["class"=>"btn btn-primary"])!!}--}}
</div> <div class="modal fade" id="modalForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content" id="modal_content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="modalDelete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Delete Confirmation</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Are you sure want to delete?</p>
                <input type="hidden" id="delete_token"/>
                <input type="hidden" id="delete_id"/>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"
                        onclick="ajaxDelete('{{url('admin/franchisors/delete')}}/'+$('#delete_id').val(),$('#delete_token').val())">
                    Delete
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
    <a href="#modalForm" data-toggle="modal" data-href="{{url('admin/franchisors/create')}}"
       class="btn btn-primary">Add Franchisor</a>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- Advanced Tables -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Franchisors
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>No</th>
                            <th>
                                 Name
                             </th>
                            <th>
                                 Email
                           </th>
                            <th>
                                 Shop
                            </th>
                            <th>
                               Coins
                            </th>
                            <th width="130px" style="vertical-align: middle">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        @php
                        $i=1;
                        @endphp
                        @foreach($franchisors as $franchisor)
                            <tr>
                                <th>{{$i++}}</th>
                                <td>{{ $franchisor->name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $franchisor->email }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $franchisor->shop}}</td>
                                <td>{{ $franchisor->coins }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" title="Edit" href="#modalForm" data-toggle="modal"
                                       data-href="{{url('admin/franchisors/update/'.$franchisor->id)}}">
                                        Edit</a>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete"/>
                                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" title="Delete" data-toggle="modal"
                                       href="#modalDelete"
                                       data-id="{{$franchisor->id}}"
                                       data-token="{{csrf_token()}}">
                                        Delete
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!--End Advanced Tables -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**Ajax/JS/Jquery:**

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.page-link', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ajaxLoad($(this).attr('href'));
});
$(document).on('submit', 'form#frm', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var data = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    var url = form.attr("action");
    $.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: url,
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $('.is-invalid').removeClass('is-invalid');
            if (data.fail) {
                for (control in data.errors) {
                    $('input[name=' + control + ']').addClass('is-invalid');
                    $('#error-' + control).html(data.errors[control]);
                }
            } else {
                $('#modalForm').modal('hide');
                //window.location.href = data.redirect_url;
                ajaxLoad(data.redirect_url);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
function ajaxLoad(filename, content) {
    content = typeof content !== 'undefined' ? content : 'content';
    $('.loading').show();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: filename,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#" + content).html(data);
            $('.loading').hide();
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
function ajaxDelete(filename, token, content) {
    content = typeof content !== 'undefined' ? content : 'content';
    $('.loading').show();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {_method: 'DELETE', _token: token},
        url: filename,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#modalDelete').modal('hide');
            $("#" + content).html(data);
            $('.loading').hide();
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
$('#modalForm').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    ajaxLoad(button.data('href'), 'modal_content');
});
$('#modalDelete').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    $('#delete_id').val(button.data('id'));
    $('#delete_token').val(button.data('token'));
});
$('#modalForm').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#focus').trigger('focus')
});
```

Any Help is much appreciated!
Thanks in advance!!